# How to replicate foreign key of another table in one to many relationship

Tags: postgresql, database-design, one-to-many, table-relationships, postgresql-9.6

I have a three table structure: `tournament`, `group` and `team`. The `tournament` and `group` tables  have a **one-to-many** relation, and `group` and `team` have a **one-to-many** relation as shown below.

[image: table structure]

How do i replicate the value of the `tournament_id` from `group` table into the `group_tournament_id` of `team` table?

i'm looking for an answer which will achieve this using the create statement like

```
create table team (
    id serial primary key, 
    group_id int references group, 
    group_tournament_id int references group(tournament_id)
);
```

of course this would not work because in order to reference something it has to be unique, in this case tournament_id is not unique

i need a standard way to copy over the value of `tournament_id` from `group` into 'team' table's `group_tournament_id` when ever i insert `group_id inside` team `table`

edit: no longer need answer in symfony, just postgreSQL would be fine

Comment: Here you have how to relation entities :http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html, and here symfony docs about mapping : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information

Comment: I think it would help if your question were a little more specific in what you are trying to do and contained some code that you might have tried.

Comment: Normally, the `team` table should have only `group_id` and should **not** have `tournament_id` at all. I don't understand why you de-normalize your schema.

Comment: in a scenario where we want to apply constraints on multiple columns a replicated foreign key would be very helpful and actually reduce the amount of relationships and simplify query a lot eg:- we want to make the combination of group_id and tournament_id [from group table] unique so that the same groups are't added to the tournament multiple times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the reference directly from `teams` to  `tournaments`. Use a trigger to automatically obtain the appropriate reference from `groups.` (Note however that the reference is not necessary as you can always get `tournament_id` from `groups` in a query. I assume that this reference is to simplify some queries).

I've slightly modified the names of tables and columns (`group` cannot be a name of a table).

Tables:

```
create table tournaments (
    tournament_id serial primary key);

create table groups (
    group_id serial primary key,
    tournament_id int references tournaments);

create table teams (
    team_id serial primary key, 
    group_id int references groups, 
    tournament_id int references tournaments);
```

Trigger:

```
create or replace function before_insert_or_update_on_teams()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    new.tournament_id = (
        select tournament_id
        from groups
        where group_id = new.group_id
        limit 1);
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger before_insert_or_update_on_teams
before insert or update on teams
for each row execute procedure before_insert_or_update_on_teams();
```

Test:

```
insert into tournaments values (default), (default);
insert into groups values (default, 2);
insert into teams values (default, 1, null);

select * from teams;

 team_id | group_id | tournament_id 
---------+----------+---------------
       1 |        1 |             2
(1 row)
```

Comment: any other ways to achieve this without triggers? OP asked alternatives to triggers

Comment: Oh, yes, I haven't read the bounty note. If I saw it I would not post the answer. But ... what's wrong with a trigger? This is the most natural and standard solution in cases like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use identifying relationships:

[image]

This produces keys which "propagate" all the way down, so you get `team.tournament_id` which is guaranteed to point to the same tournament as the parent group.

Note that I used `group_no` (not `group_id`), as a naming convention to indicate it doesn't identify the group alone, but in combination with the `tournament_id`. Ditto for `team_no`.

This complicates insertion, though. You can no longer just let the database generate the next auto-incremented ID for your group or team (because you are now identifying it with a combination of values, not just one value), but you can easily do it manually - e.g. when inserting into `group`, assign `SELECT MAX(group_no) + 1 FROM group WHERE tournament_id = ...` to the new `group_no`, and similar for the team.

BTW, this can be done **in addition** to [surrogate keys](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) (the `id` in your diagram), if you still need them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SELECT` to feed a value with `INSERT` or `UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO "teams" ("group_id", "tournament_id")
SELECT $1, "groups"."tournament_id"
  FROM "groups" WHERE ("groups"."id" = $1)
RETURNING "id"
```

This is what I am using to let Postgres insert ids for foreign keys without the (unconsistent) double query (select from groups, insert into teams).